# Are there different concepts of time?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime, time

I know that special relativity deals with the concept of time in a totally different way than classical (and quantum?) mechanics does. But are there some theories that treat time in another way? Are there some theories that are just about time? Or maybe extensions of special relativity (other than GR)?

My questions are pretty abstract and vague but I hope it'll still give some names of interesting theories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, other than GR there are theories that deal with the concept of time differently. Like in Loop Quantum Gravity spacetime is quantized, whereas in string theory it is not. One of the main problems to develop a theory of quantum gravity is the [problem of time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_time). In GR spacetime itself is dynamic but in QFTs the background spacetime is  Minkowski space. It is a big problem to combine General Relativity and Quantum theory.